# Failed a first question review audit by saying a post was spam

Tags: feature-request, spam

I reviewed a first question, which turned out to be an audit. I think the post was spam, but the system disagrees and I failed the audit.

The question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277381/defining-a-return-variable-in-the-function-declaration-is-this-legitimate-in-mo).

I am frustrated with this because the audit system does not give me a chance to explain why I think the post is spam.

So I must post this to explain my decision:

**I decided this post was spam because there is a reference to an external site called CodeSignal that I don't know and that seems to be spam.**

The question could have been posted without talking about this site.

The answer to this question is so simple that I thought that it is not a normal question.

For these reasons, I have decided that the post was spam, and reviewed it as such.

I am annoyed that Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to add a reason for that decision. Why? For 2 reasons.

1. I have read the question and I have clicked on the hyperlink to verify if this question is spam or not. I have done my work correctly.
2. It is possible that the system's decision (this question is not spam) is incorrect.

This message is only to inform SO of this problem. That's all.

**I request following change.**

1. Allow reviewers to add a comment to explain why they took the decision they did.
2. If the system considers a post not spam and a human disagrees, get a third pair of eyes to review whether it's spam or not.
3. If the third pair of eyes agrees with the system, retroactively fail the review audit.

Comment: So, why exactly is that spam? I think I'm missing something here...

Comment: Audits are chosen automatically. That question was chosen as "known good" because of its score. That question is not spam. It mentions a product, but that's fine as long as it's not spammy. Which is not in this case (no underhanded promotion, no undisclosed relation, no pattern of doing the same thing, etc).

Comment: The possibility to correct audits "manually" already exists. You act on the post outside of the queue, or you bring the situation to meta under the flag "disputed-audits". In this case, it was a good audit and you didn't pick a good choice.

Comment: @Yivi: OK I understand your point of view. But do you have clicked on CodeISignal ? You go directly on a site where Login using Facebook is possible without explaining the purpose of the site. For me, it is strange. The only easy way to go further is to accept to log using Facebook and you are immediately connected to this site.

Comment: @Yivi: your last comment is interesting. Next time, I will select this possibility :-)

Comment: You do not need to log-in to see what the site is about. From the site's description: _Get your Coding Report and Prepare for Interviews. Take our Certified Assessment to see how you compare to the rest of the industry._ The asker mentions that they found something on that site, presumably while performing a self-assessment.

Comment: I've edited your post to make the English clearer. If I got your meaning wrong anywhere, feel free to edit it further to clarify.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, spam is to be understood as unsolicited commercial advertisement. IMHO, the user provided a valid question and mentioned where they got the corresponding code from. Personally, I wouldn't rate that as spam, but maybe edit the first sentence into: "I found a strange piece of C++ grammar on CodeSignal..."

Comment: All links to external sites aren't spam.  If you think that, you need to either stop reviewing or take some time to read through the help center's guidelines on what spam is, so that you can flag spam correctly, which is exactly what failing audits like this will encourage/force you to do.

Comment: @Honk: I vote up. This is also an interesting manner to treat this case. I remove sentence that talk about CodeSignal because it is perhaps a Spam and because this page is not useful because it is the login page to CodeSignal. I will take care about your proposal next time I'm in this situation. Thanks

Comment: @schlebe Removing a citation for some quoted content turns the quotation into plagiarism, and it is not something you should be doing at all.  That's no better than incorrectly claiming it's spam.

Comment: "I decided this post was spam because there is a reference to an external site [...] that I don't know and that seems to be spam." - if you assumed it was spam entirely because you didn't know about the site, the audit did exactly what it's supposed to do. Just because you haven't heard of a site doesn't automatically make it spam, and if that's the metric you apply everywhere, you should take a second look before you flag anything as spam again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So... you want a system to review the reviewers? This is rather wrongheaded, since the *entire point* of the audit system is to be a way to review the reviewers. We put in things that are (in theory) well understood to be examples of things for which a specific action is appropriate. Therefore, if you take the wrong action, you're reviewing incorrectly.

While there have been, and continue to be, very questionable audits (of which your example is *not one*, BTW, but that's not the point), the solution to that isn't to add another layer on top. It's to remove questionable audits.

---

> I have read the question and I have clicked on the hyperlink to verify if this question is spam or not. I have done my work correctly.

FYI: no, you have not.

Whether something is spam or not is not based on where the link goes, but what the *context* of the link is. Is the post doing nothing but advertising for that site, or is the link simply part of the text of the post, a supplement (or in this case, attribution for the source of the code).

That you failed this audit is entirely correct.

> It is possible that the system's decision (this question is not spam) is incorrect.

Possible in general? Yes; bad audits exist. Possible in this specific case? No. Whatever your reasons may be, your declaration of this post as spam is *wrong*. And since you declared this to be spam, that means you probably declared several non-audit things to *also* be spam, thus harming perfectly legitimate posts.

That's bad. Learn from this experience and move on.